# How to delete specific commit histories in Github created via file upload?

Tags: github, commit, git-commit

I normally upload my files to Github repository through the web interface. I accidentally uploaded a file to Github repository recently and this file contains information which I don't want others to see. Now, this private info is permanently recorded in the commit history.

How can I delete this specific commit from Github?

*EDIT: The commit history was created through the file upload website of github. It was not created using git.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove sensitive files and their commits from Git history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872565/remove-sensitive-files-and-their-commits-from-git-history)

Comment: @sasha-dev, no. The commit history was created through the file upload website of github. It was not created using git.

Comment: just clone the repository locally and run `git reset --hard <commit_hash>~` then force push you can't do it through the interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question. Credit goes to sasha-dev for his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61767821/how-to-delete-specific-commit-histories-in-github-created-via-file-upload/61792145#comment109256325_61767821).

Here is what I did.

- Use Github desktop to clone the github repostitory.
- Launch command-line prompt. Go to the repository folder. Run the
  following command;

`git reset --hard HEAD~1  # remove last commit`

Or the goal is to remove a specific commit, find out the commit hash

```
git reset --hard <commit hash>~
```

Next step is to force push the locally made changes to the remote github repository. Run this command;

```
git push -f
```

Commits will be removed from github repository at this point.